# Using RecyclerView adapter notifyDataSetChanged in ViewPager fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

ViewPager has four fragment. In first fragment I use RecyclerView for show list of prudacts. In second fagment I manupulate of data that shows in first fragment(for example I can delete some data or add, it have to shows in first fragment Recycler view). And when I swipe to first fragment I have to see changing. For this I use notifyDataSetChanged in OnResumeFragment method. But this leads to strange behaviour of ViewPager swipe. If I delete the notifyDataSetChanged ViewPager swipe work correctly. How can I solve this issue? Any help appreciate!

Adapter

```
public class FavoriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoriteAdapter.PrudactViewHolder> {

    List<PrudactModel> prudactsList;
    public Context mContext;
    public static EditPlayerAdapterCallback callback;
    ArrayList<PrudactBusketModel> busketList = new ArrayList<>();
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    public ArrayList<Integer> tableBasket = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> tableFavorite = new ArrayList<>();

    String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public FavoriteAdapter(List<PrudactModel> persons, Context context){
        this.prudactsList = persons;
        this.mContext = context;


    }

    @Override
    public PrudactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_of_pruduct, parent, false);
        PrudactViewHolder pvh = new PrudactViewHolder(v,mContext);

        return pvh;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);


    }

    @Override
    public void  onBindViewHolder(final PrudactViewHolder prudactViewHolder, final int i) {

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        final PrudactModel p  = prudactsList.get(i);
        prudactViewHolder.catalogName.setText(p.name);
        prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setText(Integer.toString(p.price)+" тг");
        prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setText(Integer.toString(p.oldPrice)+" тг");
        prudactViewHolder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(p.imgId,imageLoader);


        //// TODO Cheking PRICE

        if (p.oldPrice==0){
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.aksia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black));
        }
        else {
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary));
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.aksia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //// TODO Cheking DB

        tableBasket = getTableBasket();
        tableFavorite = getTableFavorite();

        if (tableBasket.contains(p.id))
            prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool);
        else
            prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool1);


        if (tableFavorite.contains(p.id))
            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_d);
        else
            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_c);

        //// TODO: 02.05.2016  BUY BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.tool1).getConstantState()){
                    updateBuyButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.id);
                    cv.put("name",p.name);
                    cv.put("id_image",p.imgId);
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.price);
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.oldPrice);
                    long rowID = db.insert("basket", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to basket inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                    callback.folderClicked(1);
                }
                else {
                    updateBuyButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    callback.folderClicked(-1);
                    db.delete("basket","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.id)});
                }
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_buy.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.tool1).getConstantState()){
                    updateBuyButton(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
                    cv.put("id_prudact", p.id);
                    cv.put("name",p.name);
                    cv.put("id_image",p.imgId);
                    cv.put("count",1);
                    cv.put("price",p.price);
                    cv.put("priceOld",p.oldPrice);
                    long rowID = db.insert("basket", null, cv);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to basket inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                    callback.folderClicked(1);
                }
                else {
                    updateBuyButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    callback.folderClicked(-1);
                    db.delete("basket","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.id)});
                }
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });

        //// TODO: 02.05.2016  FAVORITE BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.favorite_c).getConstantState()){
                    cv2.put("id_prudact", p.id);
                    cv2.put("name",p.name);
                    cv2.put("id_image",p.imgId);
                    cv2.put("count",1);
                    cv2.put("price",p.price);
                    cv2.put("priceOld",p.oldPrice);
                    long rowID = db.insert("favorite", null, cv2);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to favorite inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                }

                else {
                    updateHeartButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    db.delete("favorite","id_prudact=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(p.id)});
                    delete(i);
                }
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                final ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
                final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                if (prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.getBackground().getConstantState()== ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.favorite_c).getConstantState()){
                    cv2.put("id_prudact", p.id);
                    cv2.put("name",p.name);
                    cv2.put("id_image",p.imgId);
                    cv2.put("count",1);
                    cv2.put("price",p.price);
                    cv2.put("priceOld",p.oldPrice);
                    long rowID = db.insert("favorite", null, cv2);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row to favorite inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                }
                else {
                    updateHeartButton2(prudactViewHolder, true);
                    db.delete("favorite", "id_prudact=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(p.id)});
                    delete(i);
                }
            }
        });

        //// TODO: 02.05.2016  SHARE BUTTON CLICK

        prudactViewHolder.ll_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String shareBody = "Мне нравится "+p.name+" за "+p.price+" тенге";
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Elaman" ));
            }
        });
        prudactViewHolder.btn_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String shareBody = "Мне нравится "+p.name+" за "+p.price+" тенге";
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Elaman" ));
            }
        });

        prudactViewHolder.thumbNail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image",p.imgId);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        if (p.oldPrice==0){
            prudactViewHolder.catalogPriceOld.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            prudactViewHolder.aksia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        dbHelper.close();

    }

    private static final AccelerateInterpolator ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    private static final OvershootInterpolator OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR = new OvershootInterpolator(4);

    private void updateHeartButton2(final PrudactViewHolder holder, boolean animated) {
        if (animated) {
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

            ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_favorite, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
            rotationAnim.setDuration(300);
            rotationAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_favorite, "scaleX", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimX.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimX.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_favorite, "scaleY", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimY.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimY.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);
            bounceAnimY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    holder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_c);
                }
            });

            animatorSet.play(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.play(bounceAnimX).with(bounceAnimY).after(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.start();
        }
    }

    private void updateBuyButton(final PrudactViewHolder holder, boolean animated) {
        if (animated) {
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

            ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
            rotationAnim.setDuration(300);
            rotationAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "scaleX", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimX.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimX.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "scaleY", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimY.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimY.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);
            bounceAnimY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    holder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool);
                }
            });

            animatorSet.play(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.play(bounceAnimX).with(bounceAnimY).after(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.start();
        }
    }

    private void updateBuyButton2(final PrudactViewHolder holder, boolean animated) {
        if (animated) {
            AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

            ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
            rotationAnim.setDuration(300);
            rotationAnim.setInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "scaleX", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimX.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimX.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);

            ObjectAnimator bounceAnimY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.btn_buy, "scaleY", 0.2f, 1f);
            bounceAnimY.setDuration(300);
            bounceAnimY.setInterpolator(OVERSHOOT_INTERPOLATOR);
            bounceAnimY.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    holder.btn_buy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tool1);
                }
            });

            animatorSet.play(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.play(bounceAnimX).with(bounceAnimY).after(rotationAnim);
            animatorSet.start();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return prudactsList.size();
    }

    public void setCallback(EditPlayerAdapterCallback callback2){

        callback = callback2;
    }

    public static class PrudactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CardView cv;
        TextView catalogName,catalogPrice,catalogPriceOld;
        NetworkImageView thumbNail;
        ImageButton btn_favorite,btn_share, btn_buy;
        LinearLayout ll_buy,aksia,ll_share,ll_favorite;

        public PrudactViewHolder(View itemView,Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            catalogName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_catalog);
            catalogPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_catalog);
            catalogPriceOld = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.old_price_catalog);

            btn_buy = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);
            btn_share = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
            btn_favorite = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.izbrannyi);

            thumbNail = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_catalog);
            aksia = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aksia);
            ll_buy = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_buy);
            ll_share = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_share);
            ll_favorite = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_favorite);

            catalogPriceOld.setPaintFlags(catalogPriceOld.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        }

    }

    ArrayList<Integer> getTableBasket(){

        ArrayList<Integer> id_list = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("basket", null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            int id_prudactColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id_prudact");

            do {

                id_list.add(c.getInt(id_prudactColIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In basket 0 rows");
        c.close();

        return id_list;
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> getTableFavorite(){

        ArrayList<Integer> id_list = new ArrayList<>();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query("favorite", null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            int id_prudactColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id_prudact");

            do {

                id_list.add(c.getInt(id_prudactColIndex));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In favorite 0 rows");
        c.close();

        return id_list;
    }

    public void delete(int position) { //removes the row
        prudactsList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, prudactsList.size());
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class C_Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle,EditPlayerAdapterCallback {

    PrudactModel prudact = new PrudactModel();
    RecyclerView rv;
    PrudactAdapter adapter;
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    public static BasketListener basketclick;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, null);

//        mainActivity.setfragmentclick(this);

        rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(rv.getContext());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        prudact.initializeData();
        adapter = new PrudactAdapter(prudact.prudactList,getActivity());
        adapter.setCallback(this);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeFragment() {


        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Акции и новинки");
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.ic_menu_basket);
        LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select *from basket ", null);
        int cnt = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        Utils.setBadgeCount(getActivity(), icon,cnt);
    }

    void setBasketclick(BasketListener bl){
        basketclick = bl;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(0,true);
        }
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.ic_menu_basket){
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(3, true);
            basketclick.basketClicked();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    backAction();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void backAction() {

        if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        else  {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(0, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void folderClicked(int position) {
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of using notifydatasetchanged try setting the updated list to the adapter again. like: myadapter.setAdapter(updated_list);

Comment: @RicardoBarroca I tried but it shows the same result like notifyadapter

Comment: Whats the strange behavior exactly?

Comment: @RicardoBarroca Without notifyadapter transition occurs smoothly. And And with notifyadapter a smooth transition disappears instead of transition occurs quickly